# Created new project in django using virtualenv and its running fine but when I trying to create new app using 'startapp' and again running project

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

Created new project in django using virtualenv and its running fine but when I trying to create new app using 'startapp' and again running project by command :
python3.6 advertisement/manage.py runserver localhost:8000

```
then throw error : 
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f57db4171e0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ravinder/advertisement/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ravinder/advertisement/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/home/ravinder/advertisement/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/home/ravinder/advertisement/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/home/ravinder/advertisement/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ravinder/advertisement/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/ravinder/advertisement/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/home/ravinder/advertisement/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
```

Note : I already added app in setting.py installed app.

Please help me to reoslve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add some code of INSTALLED_APPS.You were just saying django to add an app "core" which is inside mysite folder , and django is not able to found it.

1) remove mysite.core, and run migrate.

2)create a app core inside mysite. and create an app means it should have app.py file. and it contain

or you have mention your app in INSTALLED_APPS like this

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
       'django.contrib.admin', 
       'django.contrib.auth', 
       'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
       'django.contrib.sessions', 
       'django.contrib.messages', 
       'django.contrib.staticfiles', 

       'mysite.core', 
]
```

then your directory should be like this

```
mysite/
 ├── core
 │     ├── __init__.py
 │     └── views.py
 └── __init__.py
```

Answer (score 0):

That type of error occurs only when You create an app and make your urls but you don’t create function in views.py file which you refer in urls.py file. Solution are following below:

1. Declared your app name in settings.py file
2. Declared your url in main urls.py file
3. Declared your url in your app urls.py file
4. Declared your function in views.py file which you make reference in your app urls.py file
   *Now, you are able to run your server by two methods.*

> python manage.py runserver
>
> python3.6 manage.py runserver